# transforming rules into lists

Tags: list, prolog

i want to get data from rules into a list in order to be farther processed,
for example i have:

course_meetings(comm401,tutorial,t07,mohamed_esameldin,'tutorial for t07').
course_meetings(comm401,tutorial,t08,sally_mahmoud,'tutorial for t08').
course_meetings(comm401,tutorial,t09,mohamed_esameldin,'tutorial for t09').
course_meetings(comm401,tutorial,t10,sally_mahmoud,'tutorial for t10').
course_meetings(comm401,lecture,all_group_4,dr_amr_talaat,'lecture 1').

i want to transform this rules into a list like this:
[[comm401,tutorial,t07,mohamed_esameldin,'tutorial for t07'],       [comm401,tutorial,t08,sally_mahmoud,'tutorial for t08'],
[comm401,tutorial,t09,mohamed_esameldin,'tutorial for t09']]

Thanks in advance for your help i am a newbie in prolog and hope my question isnt Vague,
also if there is a better way to process this data please direct me,
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `?- findall([A,B,C,D,E], course_meetings(A,B,C,D,E), L).`

Comment: It worked however, its gives the first 4 facts then start giving me lists in form of [CSEN401|.....],[...|...]|......]
i tried increasing stack size to 4gb but still it didnt work 
i used this command "#!/usr/bin/swipl -G4g -s"

Comment: It's just the way SWI-Prolog compress too large structure for display. The values are there. Try for instance `?- findall(...),maplist(writeln,L).`

Comment: but if i want to use them they r there, for instance i will have to make permutations and test certain constrains will that work